# HOC with typescript (AppComponent)

Tags: typescript

```
import { ComponentProps, Dispatch, SetStateAction, useState } from 'react';

export interface WithProjectProps extends ComponentProps<any> {
  test: boolean;
  setTest: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

export default function withProject(AppComponent: ComponentProps<any>) {
  return function WrappedAppComponent(props: WithProjectProps) {
    const [test, setTest] = useState(false);

    return <AppComponent {...props} test={test} setTest={setTest} />;
  };
}
```

```
ComponentProps<any>
```

I do not want to use "any" type for this component
but I tried many times to exchange the "any" but it won't work.

```
ComponentProps<any> =>  ComponentProps<**something**>
```